# JSON.stringify an object with Knockout JS variables

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

Current scenario:

```
function Employee(data) {
var self = this;

// variables
this.Forename = ko.observable(data.Forename);
this.Surname = ko.observable(data.Surname);

this.Save = function () {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(self); // Without ko.observables, this works fine. self() doesn't work obviously.
    console.log(obj);
};
}
```

I think what I'm trying to do is pretty straight forward, get all the observable values without going through every single one of them, and creating a JSON string using the stringify function. This is easy to do without observables, is there a simple way to do it with them?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Knockout has a built in [toJSON](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) function to do exactly this:

```
var json = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

> **ko.toJSON** — this produces a JSON string representing your view model’s data. Internally, it simply calls ko.toJS on your view model, and then uses the browser’s native JSON serializer on the result. **Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the json2.js library.**

Comment: Actually, this is even better as it doesn't require another library. Awesome.

Comment: i think you have first to convert the observable into normal JS object then call ko.toJSON on it.

Comment: True, I tend to use the mapping one in case I need the greater flexibility of ignoring certain properties. Also, I can't see any reference in the mapping documentation about whether it needs json2.js to work in older browsers. If it doesn't, then that's obviously an advantage.

Comment: @PaulManzotti Just checked the source code and the mapping plugin uses ko.utils.stringifyJson which has the same requirements of a built in serializer.

Comment: @RichardDalton Ah, cheers for looking into that, good to know.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by 2 ways :

first:

```
      var json = ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel))
```

Second

```
      var json = JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel))
```

Comment: And then ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS($root), null, 2) :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)?

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
```

Comment: One of those "d'oh, why didn't I think of that?" moments! Cheers :)