# Serialize nested observable arrays to JSON

Tags: knockout.js

In KnockoutJS is there a way to serialize nested structures of observable arrays to JSON?
I am using JSON.stringify, but since it doesn't access the arrays as someObservableArray(), it will not be able to serialize the nested arrays:

Ex: I have an observable array where each item contains an observable array as a property .

Currently I am manually converting it to a standard JS object before calling JSON.stringify, but is there another knockout function that will enable me to convert it to JSON directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify an object with Knockout JS variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087710/json-stringify-an-object-with-knockout-js-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`ko.toJSON` function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) which can serialize nested observable structures to JSON:

```
var vm = {
    someObservableArray: ko.observableArray(
    [{
        prop: ko.observable('val1'),
        childArray: ko.observableArray([{
            prop2: ko.observable('vla2')
        }, {
            prop2: ko.observable('val3')
        }])
    }, {
        prop: ko.observable('val4'),
        childArray: ko.observableArray([{
            prop2: ko.observable('val5')
        }, {
            prop2: ko.observable('val6')
        }])
    }])
}
console.log(ko.toJSON(vm));
// output: {"someObservableArray":[{"prop":"val1","childArray":[{"prop2":"vla2"},
//         {"prop2":"val3"}]},{"prop":"val4","childArray":[{"prop2":"val5"},
//         {"prop2":"val6"}]}]}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggQJN/).